# What is the record for the most stalemates in one?

Tags: problems, records, stalemate

Is there a known record for the most possible stalemates in one in a legal position, for with and without promoted pieces? I did some constructing myself for a start.

For without promoted pieces, I found **105**, counting different promotions as different moves.

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 2/24/2020, Stalemate In 1"]
[FEN "kN6/P1PPPPPP/2P5/4K3/6Q1/2NBB3/1R6/R7 w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

For promoted pieces, I remembered a position from [elsewhere on this site.](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4490/15543) I switched two pieces, made come counting deductions, and I arrived at a number of **205** moves for with promoted pieces.

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 2/24/2020, Stalemate In 1"]
[FEN "R6B/3Q4/1Q4Q1/4Q3/2Q4Q/Q4Q2/pp1Q4/kBNN1KR1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Your "with promoted pieces" currently has 9 queens and 3 bishops, so it seems illegal.

Comment: What about stalemate by repetition? If you were to give the black king two squares to move between, you would have a huge number of different combinations that produce a threefold repetition...

Comment: @Aric that is called Draw by repitition

Comment: The first position isn't legal, there's no possible previous move for black.
The third position is already a draw, since there's no possible sequence of moves that will lead to either player getting mated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to find the ultimate records in the [Die Schwable Chess Problem Database.](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/index.jsp)

---

```
[Title "Anthony Stewart & Mackay Dickens, Feenschach 9/1969, 113 Stalemating Moves"]
[FEN "6R1/PPPPPP2/7R/1K6/2N1BN2/2B4p/P4P1k/3Q4 w - - 0 1"]
```

[Source Page](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P0005616)

---

```
[Title "Anthony Stewart & Mackay Dickens, Feenschach 1/1969, 211 Stalemating Moves"]
[FEN "4Q2R/1K4Q1/3Q4/Q4Q2/2Q4Q/4Q3/1Q4Rp/1N1BB1Nk w - - 0 1"]
```

[Source Page](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P1178842)