# What is the highest mobility score of a board without a checkmate, stalemate, or draw?

Tags: engines, problems, evaluation, mathematics

I consider the mobility score of a board to be the number of legal moves one player could make less the number of legal moves the other player could make.

```
8/7k/2Q2K2/8/6b1/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
```

Using the board above, white king has 3 legal moves, white bishop has 9 legal moves, black king has 4 legal moves, and black queen has 11 legal moves. According to white, the mobility score of this board is `(3 + 9) - (4 + 11) = 12 - 15 = -3`.

What is the maximum mobility score possible of a board which is not a terminal case (checkmate, stalemate, draw) keeping consideration for a legal number of pieces (ie. maximum of 9 queens, 2 rooks, 2 bishops, 2 knights, 1 king of each color)?

I don't really care if the board configuration is impossible to get to (it's probably possible to have 9 queens on the board and not be a checkmate/stalemate, but not possible to get to that state without a checkmate/stalemate), I only care that the configuration is legal.

I've written a chess engine which uses a heuristic which considers the mobility score of a board. I want to know the maximum possible mobility score so I can better define the value of a checkmate, check, etc. There's no point in setting a checkmate to, say, 200, if the mobility score of a board can exceed this, yet I don't want to define a checkmate as an arbitrary number: it need only be the highest mobility score plus one.

Comment: Adding the moves would make more sense than subtracting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but here’s “my” suggestion of a total mobility **215** in a legal configuration. White has 216 total moves, minus away one for Black’s only legal move for total.

```
[FEN "1Q5R/4Q1K1/B1Q5/B4Q2/N2Q4/pQ4Q1/pn2Q3/krQ4R w - - 0 1"]
```

This position was originally created by [William Shinkman](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/search.jsp?expression=probid=%27P1182014%27) as the record for the most mates in two. This position’s mobility will be very hard to beat, as it has no checkmate/stalemates in one, in addition to how the known maximum for any move is [218](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/maximum-possible-movement-in-a-turn/8392#8392) contains so many checkmating/stalemating move that it won’t work here.